# Trying to get date of Birth for a user if it is is not an Adult via <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to collect the date of birth for a user if he specifies that he is Under18....

I have defined 2 claims as follows

```
    <ClaimType Id="extension_DateofBirth">
         <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
         <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
         <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
   </ClaimType>
    
       <!--Adding  Custom Attribute for AgeGroup -->
 <ClaimType Id="extension_AgeGroup">
         <DisplayName>Your Age Group</DisplayName>
         <DataType>string</DataType>
         <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
         <Restriction>
           <Enumeration Text="Under 18" Value="Under18" />
           <Enumeration Text="Adult" Value="Adult" />
         </Restriction>
 </ClaimType>
```

Now in my

I have added the following code in

```
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Get-DOB" ContinueOnError="false">
     <Preconditions>
       <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_AgeGroup</Value>
          <Value>Under18</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
     </Preconditions>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

and another Technical Profile as follows that is referenced "Get-DOB". which is as follows

```
   <!--Adding write of DOB based on validation Profile-->
      <TechnicalProfile Id="Get-DOB">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_DateofBirth" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_DateofBirth" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
 </TechnicalProfiles>
```

I have 2 issues:

1. if I select Under18 the DOB should appear on the screen which it is not.
2. After I select Under18 and press continue the explorer gets stuck on
   we are processing your information forever

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got this working by getting the preconditions done in the User Journey and not using validation technical Profiles